# npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install on my dependencies from an already existing react project using npm install, however, is giving me this error every time now I try to run npm install.

Does anyone know why is this happening now? I have several projects that I have been working on before installing and uninstalling with no problem at all.

````
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.0.6: Please update: there are crash fixes
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm ERR! path /Users/gabrielnessi/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/35/e4/300bcd6d6b07328b3cffb3509f86bc1ac535a870f8fe27c074a299d8c732
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/gabrielnessi/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/35/e4/300bcd6d6b07328b3cffb3509f86bc1ac535a870f8fe27c074a299d8c732'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/gabrielnessi/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/35/e4/300bcd6d6b07328b3cffb3509f86bc1ac535a870f8fe27c074a299d8c732'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/gabrielnessi/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/35/e4/300bcd6d6b07328b3cffb3509f86bc1ac535a870f8fe27c074a299d8c732'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!     path: '/Users/gabrielnessi/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/35/e4/300bcd6d6b07328b3cffb3509f86bc1ac535a870f8fe27c074a299d8c732'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, open ' +
npm ERR!     "'/Users/gabrielnessi/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/35/e4/300bcd6d6b07328b3cffb3509f86bc1ac535a870f8fe27c074a299d8c732'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/gabrielnessi/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/35/e4/300bcd6d6b07328b3cffb3509f86bc1ac535a870f8fe27c074a299d8c732',
npm ERR!   parent: 'eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gabrielnessi/.npm/_logs/2019-06-13T11_28_05_702Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: some dependencies need you to have super user access. Try sudo npm install

Comment: @MehulMittal this is the second time it happens and first time I solved with sudo yes, but I don't want to be using sudo every time I have to install a package, is there a way to get my permissions right? thanks

Comment: What is the path of your project

Comment: @MehulMittal Documents/react_course/react-complete-guide (on macbook)

Comment: do a `npm cache clean` or `npm cache clean --force` if it doesn't work try with `sudo`. Because most probably your cache is corrupted. Then install the packages.

Comment: please add a log of `ls -l` in the `Documents/react_course/` directory.

Comment: @GabrielNessi run chmod -R 777 Documents/react_course  and try npm install again

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I tried npm cache clean and it tells me to verify it instead, I ran npm verify and it gave me same error, so I ran (as advice by npm) npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache but again same error.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty When I try ls -l this is what I get:
total 1240
-rw-r--r--     1 gabrielnessi  staff  121322  4 Jun 23:17 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  1007 gabrielnessi  staff   32224 13 Jun 13:51 node_modules
-rw-r--r--     1 gabrielnessi  staff  506644 13 Jun 13:39 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--     1 gabrielnessi  staff     382 13 Jun 13:43 package.json
drwxr-xr-x     5 gabrielnessi  staff     160  5 Jun 00:49 public
drwxr-xr-x     9 gabrielnessi  staff     288 13 Jun 12:09 src

Comment: @GabrielNessi use the --force flag, `npm cache clean --force` if it doens't work use `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably create your project as root, and now you try to install module on the same folder as a simple user. You need to login as root to give permissions to user, or change the folder owner or delete and recreate your project folder

Comment: Right. More on this, just add your user to as the owner of `/Users/gabrielnessi/.npm/`. Try `sudo chown -R $USER /Users/gabrielnessi/.npm/`. Of course replacing gabrielnessi with your correct username, or the path.